# Pull Data From Last 10 Minutes

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have created a SQL statement that pulls the data we need from our database for an auto generated alert. The SQL is below:

```
select t.ps_ticket_id,
   l.loc_desc,
   n.descrip,
   a.itemno,
   p.print_last_date
from fgmulti f, 
   locations l,
   V_ps_tickets t,
   non_conform n,
   arinvt a,
   ps_ticket p
where f.loc_id = l.id and
   f.arinvt_id = t.arinvt_id and 
   n.id = f.non_conform_id and 
   f.arinvt_id = a.id and
   p.id = t.ps_ticket_id
```

I am looking to write SQL that looks at our time stamp being pulled from p.print_last_date . I would like for it to pull only data populated from within the last 10 minutes. Is this possible?

Comment: Which column would indicate the desired time stamp, is it different from `print_last_date` ?  It would make the query easier to read if you used the `JOIN` clauses.

Comment: Maybe add this to WHERE condition: `AND p.our_timestamp >= current_timestamp - interval '10' minute`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just FYI, the code that you're using, while it works, isn't up to the ANSI standard which is now almost 20 years old. This separates joins from the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT t.ps_ticket_id, l.loc_desc, n.descrip, a.itemno, p.print_last_date
  FROM fgmulti f
 INNER JOIN locations l
    ON f.loc_id = l.id
 INNER JOIN v_ps_tickets t
    ON f.arinvt_id = t.arinvt_id
 INNER JOIN non_conform n
    ON n.id = f.non_conform_id 
 INNER JOIN arinvt a
    ON f.arinvt_id = a.id
 INNER JOIN ps_ticket p
    ON p.id = t.ps_ticket_id
 WHERE p.print_last_date >= SYSDATE - 1/144;
```

(Since there are 1,440 minutes in a day, 1/144 = 10 minutes. You can also use intervals, e.g., `- INTERVAL '10' MINUTE`, but I don't see a good reason to conform to the ANSI standard here when using a non-standard function -- `SYSDATE` -- anyway.)

Hope this helps.

Comment: This works perfect. Thank you for your help and for the additional information!

Answer (score 1):

```
... and p.timestamp_column > sysdate - 10 / (24 * 60)
```

You'd subtract 10 minutes from `SYSDATE` (which is precise up to seconds). `24 * 60` represents "24 hours in a day" and "60 minutes in an hour". You need to do it that way because - when two `DATE` datatype values are subtracted, result is number of **days** between them.

Or, you could subtract interval, such as

```
... and p.timestamp_column > sysdate - interval '10' minute
```

For example:

```
SQL> select sysdate,
  2         sysdate - 10 / (24 * 60) ten_minutes_ago_1,
  3         sysdate - interval '10' minute ten_minutes_ago_2
  4  from dual;

SYSDATE             TEN_MINUTES_AGO_1   TEN_MINUTES_AGO_2
------------------- ------------------- -------------------
09.07.2018 22:11:04 09.07.2018 22:01:04 09.07.2018 22:01:04

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response! I see I did not word my question correctly. I am looking to pull data within the past 10 minuets from: select p.print_last_date

Comment: OK, so - instead of my `p.timestamp_column` put your `p.print_last_date`. The rest shouldn't be changed.

Answer (score 1):

```
select sysdate, sysdate - interval '10' minute as minus_10_mins  from dual;


"SYSDATE","MINUS_10_MINS"
09-JUL-2018 20:09:41,09-JUL-2018 19:59:41
```

Answer (score -2):

This works in TSQL, but I think you'll need to look up the Oracle version of the DateAdd function:

```
select t.ps_ticket_id,
   l.loc_desc,
   n.descrip,
   a.itemno,
   p.print_last_date
from fgmulti f, 
   locations l,
   V_ps_tickets t,
   non_conform n,
   arinvt a,
   ps_ticket p
where f.loc_id = l.id and
   f.arinvt_id = t.arinvt_id and 
   n.id = f.non_conform_id and 
   f.arinvt_id = a.id and
   p.id = t.ps_ticket_id AND
   p.print_last_date > DATEADD(MINUTE, -10, GETDATE());
```